# When non-blocking assignment used inside procedural block,will it be considered as concurrent flow?

Tags: verilog

When non-blocking assignment is used inside procedural block, will it be considered as a concurrent flow? What would the scenario be? I am little confused about. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

The things which are simulated concurrently in verilog are `always` blocks themselves. The code inside a single `always`  block is executed sequentially. Concurrency does not depend on blocking/non-blocking assignments.

`blocking`/`non-blocking` assignments are used to work around one of a fundamental deficiencies in verilog:  inability to correctly simulate behavior of a state device: a flop or a latch. The `non-blocking` assignment is a trick to prioritize event scheduling order to fix the above.